# Angular call function every 5 seconds

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular project, and we have a screen in which data from our database is shown in a graph format, however, if the user changes some settings this goes through some calculating and a 'loading graphic is displayed. However, the graphic does not disappear after the calculations have been finished, the user must refresh the page.

The graphic `<div>` uses `*ngIf="isRecalculating()"` to determine whether it should be shown or not.

```
isRecalculating(): boolean {
    return this.graph && this.graph.status === 'recalculating';
  }
```

So, what I need is for the app to check every 5 seconds while it is recalculating, to determine if recalculating has finished.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with rxjs

```
check$: Observable<boolean>;        

check$ = interval(5000).pipe(
    map(() => this.isRecalculating())
)
```

and in html

```
<div *ngIf="check$ | async">
```

dont forget to unsubscribe

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, where would I out the ``check$ = ...`` in my component.ts file? Inside the ``ngOnInit``?

Comment: Ok, I have implemented it, but my graphic or graph display for 5 seconds

Comment: And i get the error ``Type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`` for the ``this.check$ =-.``

Comment: can you create a stackblitz or plunkr?

Comment: It is a huge project

Comment: @ThorstenRintelen you misused the `of`, just remove it and see the error go away. Also, maybe replace the `map` with `mapTo` as you don't care about the source?